# 'innerText' doesn't work in EditableColumn Class

Tags: javascript, dom, yii2, innertext

```
            'editableOptions'=>[
                'name'=>'type',
                'inputType' => kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,
                'data'=>$parent,
                'pluginEvents' => [
                    'editableSuccess' =>"function(event, val) {
                        var list = '".json_encode($type)."';
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(list);
                          for(var item in event.target.children){
                                if(item == 0){
                                    event.target.children[item].innerText = 'hello';                                        //console.log(event.target.children[item].textContent); 
                                }
                            }

                    }",
                ]
            ],
```

the console.log values is right ,but my browser to display the wrong values,not "hello" value. where is error ?

Comment: after "hello" assign, try console.log(event.target.children[item].innerText) and check your output whether it is ok or not

Comment: the console.log display "hello",but the browser not .